# VBA how to run code on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know how to run code from one workbook in another workbook.

Code example:

```
Set dlsheet = appexcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "dlsheet.csv")

With dlsheet.Sheets("data")

    numofrows = Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("I:I").Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

end with
```

I know this isn't a full extract of code that I want to run, but how do I make it so that it doesn't count the number of rows in the workbook that I'm running the code from rather that dlsheet.

Any help or advice would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Check the following [link1](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47315) and [link2](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/374909-open-a-closed-workbook-with-vba.html)

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically run a macro found in another workbook? Or how to apply your code to a workbook OTHER than the one you are in (i.e. instead of the active workbook)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `with` you can using a `.` to reference the references sheet:

```
Set dlsheet = appexcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "dlsheet.csv")

With dlsheet.Sheets("data")

    numofrows = .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

    .Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

end with
```